# VS 2010: "Always Create" was specified

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am trying to compile a c++ simulation, that was previously written in VS2008. 
It gives error exe not created, because "Always Create" was specified. 
I have tried every solution, edited devenv.xml, changed verbosity output. Kindly anyone could give any idea.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This problem will occur when one of the include files listed in the project doesn't actually exist. You may have deleted the file, but forgot to remove it from the project.

The dependency checker then believes the project is not up to date, but the builder finds nothing to build.

A quick check that all project files can open in editor will help you fix this problem.

Comment: checked that, anyother solution.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it could be because a dependency, or the verbosity output level. Here are more options to you to take into account:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/38c08137-3bb0-4143-b97f-72d077646318/visual-c-2010-build-questionissue?forum=vcgeneral